# Incorrect mapping URL of SAPUI5 app on Fiori Launchpad

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

I have two SAPUI5 apps and they both are working well, but there is a problem with them on Fiori launchpad. The initially opened app gets the correct url to our rest service (.json), but after I click the `Home` button and go to the second app the url gets put together incorrectly, because the resource-path of the second App still contains the folder of the initial App.

```
1. .../app1folder/app1resource
2. .../app1folder/app2resource
```

Correct would be:

```
2. .../app2folder/app2resource
```

The resources we use are created as destinations in the SAP HANA Cloud Platform Cockpit>Connectivity>Destinations

Neo-app.json

```
{
      "path": "/app1resource",
      "target": {
        "type": "destination",
        "name": "app1"
      },
      "description": "app1 API"
    }
```

How can I manually change the "appfolder"-directory (app1folder, app2folder)? Or is it automatically created by the fiori launchpad and unaccessible?

My application is built from scratch and not generated and maybe there's a common mistake.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem:
Both apps had the same id and as a result the launchpad couldn't load the applicationfiles into the scope.

Solution:
I changed the app id and all related references in the controllers, modules... .